# What components support working with adapters

Tags: android, android-adapter, baseadapter

Like `ListView` are there other components and widgets were we can use adapters (i.e. inherited from `BaseAdapter`) in android framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView, GridView, Spinner and Gallery for commonly used subclasses of AdapterView.

and also

AdapterViewFlipper, ExpandableListView, StackView.

basically all the classes implementing  **android.widget.AdapterView** use adapterview.